# Estimating a Filter's Envelope

Tags: filters, estimation, envelope

Are there any established techniques for estimating the envelope of a swept filter? I tried a first order piece-wise polynomial approximation using the SHGO global minimizer algorithm (Python code below), but it fails. Setting the points by hand approximately succeeds.

The purpose for the estimation is to obtain a synthesizer's filter decay envelope, after the filter is known. The input is thereby one of the typical waveforms a synthesizer can generate, in the code a sawtooth waveform was chosen.

```
import numpy
import scipy.optimize
import scipy.signal

#2nd order low pass filter
def filt(X,F,X0=0,X1=0,Y0=0,Y1=0,resonance=1):
    X=numpy.append(X,[X1,X0])
    Y=numpy.zeros(len(F))
    Y=numpy.append(Y,[Y1,Y0])
    for i in range(len(F)):
        wd=F[i]*2*numpy.pi
        T=1/88200
        d=resonance
        C=numpy.tan(wd*T/2)

        D=(1+d*C+C**2)
        a1=2*(C**2-1)/D
        a2=(1-d*C+C**2)/D


        b0=C**2/D
        b1=2*b0
        b2=b0
        
        Y[i]=-a1*Y[i-1]-a2*Y[i-2]+b0*X[i]+b1*X[i-1]+b2*X[i-2]
    return Y[0:len(Y)-2]

#X = filter input, Y = Output.
freq=600
t=numpy.linspace(0, 1, 88200)
X=scipy.signal.sawtooth(2 * numpy.pi * freq * t)
F=freq+5*freq*numpy.e**(-t*40)      #Envelope
Y=filt(X,F)
Y+=numpy.random.normal(0,0.075,len(Y))

#Estimation (Result in Fest):
def PolMin(X,P,I,X0,X1,Y0,Y1):
    F=numpy.zeros(I[1]-I[0])
    F=numpy.polyval(P,range(I[1]-I[0]))
    Y=filt(X[I[0]:I[1]],F,X0,X1,Y0,Y1)
    return Y

def Target(P,I,X0,X1,Y0,Y1):
    return numpy.sum((PolMin(X,P,I,X0,X1,Y0,Y1)-Y[I[0]:I[1]])**2)

chunkl=200
length=25000
chunks=int(25000/200)
Results = numpy.zeros([chunks,2])
B=[(-2,0),(0,10000)]
Y0=0
Y1=0
X0=0
X1=0
Z=numpy.zeros(length+1)
Fest=numpy.zeros(length+1)
for i in range(chunks):
    chunkst=i*chunkl
    chunke=chunkl*(i+1)+1
    f=lambda x: Target(x,(chunkst,chunke),X0,X1,Y0,Y1)
    Results[i,:]=scipy.optimize.shgo(f,B,iters=4).x
    endpoint=numpy.polyval(Results[i,:],chunkl*(i+1))
    B=[(-1,1),(endpoint,endpoint)]
    Fest[chunkst:chunke]=numpy.polyval(Results[i,:],range(chunkl+1))
    Z[chunkst:chunke]=filt(X[chunkst:chunke],Fest[chunkst:chunke],X0,X1,Y0,Y1)
    Y0=Z[chunke-2]
    Y1=Z[chunke-3]
    X0=X[chunke-2]
    X1=X[chunke-3]
```

Comment: What is the input to estimate the filter from? Try to make the question clearer.

Comment: @Royi I hope the purpose and question regarding input is clear enough now. If you have any further questions please ask and I will provide an answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't get it. Do you have a known input file which undergoes a linear filtering and you have the result as well? Are you after estimating filter by deconvolution?

Comment: @Royi The input is a sawtooth waveform, so the code simulates a sawtooth. In reality I would also have to match the phase of the sawtooth, but this is not as difficult. So I know the input waveform, output waveform and the filter. I want to capture the envelope that sweeps the filter downwards from a higher pitch to a lower one.

Comment: I am sorry. I don't' get it. do you have a model of convolution between a saw tooth and a filter? You the input and the output but not the filter?

Comment: @Royi I have the filter, but it's not static. It is swept from 3600 hz to 600 hz in the code. I want to capture the exponentialish curve that modulates the filter downwards in frequency, which I do not know, not the filter itself. The difficulty may be that usually we deal with filters that are static, not changing in frequency. In this case the filter coefficients are changing until the end of the sweep is reached.

Comment: i am not reading python code.  when i think of the term "swept filter", i am thinking of a time-variant linear system in which the filter's resonant frequency is swept over a range of frequencies over time.  is that it?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson That is exactly it indeed. Audio synthesizers can sweep the frequency upon playing a note to create a "pluck" sound. It is possible import sounddevice and type in sounddevice.play(Y) to hear how it sounds on the example. I am interested in capturing the shape of the downward sloping modulation envelope.